# How to return a nested JSon object in a key value store object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a [simplified] JSON file like

```
{
   "id":87,
   "meta_data":[
      {
         "id":1232,
         "key":"user_created_by",
         "value":"example@gmail.com"
      },
      {
         "id":1233,
         "key":"user_created_at",
         "value":"1659890457477"
      },
      {
         "id":1234,
         "key":"good_person_or_silly_sausage",
         "value":"No"
      }      
   ]
}
```

I want to do something like

`Logger.log(orderDetailsObject.meta_data.value[key="good_person_or_silly_sausage"])`

The expected value would be

> No

However, this isn't what's occurring. At present I'm being told that the object is null.

I think it's because the meta_data object is an object in an object or two dimensional array or something? I don't have a good understand of what I'm doing here,

I feel like
https://docs.jsonata.org/simple
and
https://docs.jsonata.org/predicate
Should be guiding me towards the answer - but I'm not getting something I think.

I'm a newbie to SO and JSON & Javascript - so please be gentle. <3

**EDIT:** None-simplified actual json file below:

```
{
   "id":87,
   "parent_id":0,
   "status":"pending",
   "currency":"USD",
   "version":"6.5.1",
   "prices_include_tax":false,
   "date_created":"2022-08-07T16:40:57",
   "date_modified":"2022-08-11T10:13:07",
   "discount_total":"0.00",
   "discount_tax":"0.00",
   "shipping_total":"0.00",
   "shipping_tax":"0.00",
   "cart_tax":"0.00",
   "total":"1100.00",
   "total_tax":"0.00",
   "customer_id":17,
   "order_key":"wc_order_omQo7nW5yCS9X",
   "billing":{
      "first_name":"",
      "last_name":"",
      "company":"",
      "address_1":"",
      "address_2":"",
      "city":"",
      "state":"",
      "postcode":"",
      "country":"",
      "email":"freddie@example.com",
      "phone":""
   },
   "shipping":{
      "first_name":"",
      "last_name":"",
      "company":"",
      "address_1":"",
      "address_2":"",
      "city":"",
      "state":"",
      "postcode":"",
      "country":"",
      "phone":""
   },
   "payment_method":"",
   "payment_method_title":"",
   "transaction_id":"",
   "customer_ip_address":"",
   "customer_user_agent":"",
   "created_via":"rest-api",
   "customer_note":"",
   "date_completed":null,
   "date_paid":"2022-08-07T16:40:58",
   "cart_hash":"",
   "number":"87",
   "meta_data":[
      {
         "id":1232,
         "key":"user_created_by",
         "value":"example@gmail.com"
      },
      {
         "id":1233,
         "key":"user_created_at",
         "value":"1659890457477"
      },
      {
         "id":1234,
         "key":"good_person_or_silly_sausage",
         "value":"No"
      },
      {
         "id":1235,
         "key":"order_request_high_chair",
         "value":"yes"
      },
      {
         "id":1240,
         "key":"order_notes",
         "value":"They're on their honeymoon"
      },
      {
         "id":1241,
         "key":"pricing_notes",
         "value":"They're on their honeymoon"
      },
      {
         "id":1242,
         "key":"order_booked_by",
         "value":"me on me"
      },
      {
         "id":1243,
         "key":"order_referral_source",
         "value":"Newspaper"
      },
      {
         "id":1244,
         "key":"commission_percent",
         "value":"13"
      },
      {
         "id":1245,
         "key":"discount_percent",
         "value":"5"
      },
      {
         "id":1246,
         "key":"deposit_paid_date",
         "value":"today"
      },
      {
         "id":1247,
         "key":"damage_bond_date_paid",
         "value":"today"
      },
      {
         "id":1248,
         "key":"damage_bond",
         "value":"100"
      },
      {
         "id":1249,
         "key":"start_date",
         "value":"01\/01\/01"
      },
      {
         "id":1250,
         "key":"deposit_payment_amount",
         "value":"500"
      },
      {
         "id":1251,
         "key":"order_request_welcome_pack_wine_type",
         "value":"Red"
      },
      {
         "id":1252,
         "key":"end_date",
         "value":"02\/02\/02"
      },
      {
         "id":1259,
         "key":"_new_order_email_sent",
         "value":"true"
      },
      {
         "id":1260,
         "key":"_automatewoo_order_created",
         "value":"1"
      }
   ],
   "line_items":[
      {
         "id":45,
         "name":"Villa Booking",
         "product_id":0,
         "variation_id":0,
         "quantity":1,
         "tax_class":"",
         "subtotal":"1000.00",
         "subtotal_tax":"0.00",
         "total":"1000.00",
         "total_tax":"0.00",
         "taxes":[
            
         ],
         "meta_data":[
            {
               "id":411,
               "key":"Dates",
               "value":"01\/01\/01 until 02\/02\/02",
               "display_key":"Dates",
               "display_value":"01\/01\/01 until 02\/02\/02"
            }
         ],
         "sku":null,
         "price":1000,
         "parent_name":null
      },
      {
         "id":46,
         "name":"Standard Welcome Pack",
         "product_id":73,
         "variation_id":0,
         "quantity":2,
         "tax_class":"",
         "subtotal":"0.00",
         "subtotal_tax":"0.00",
         "total":"0.00",
         "total_tax":"0.00",
         "taxes":[
            
         ],
         "meta_data":[
            {
               "id":421,
               "key":"Wine Type",
               "value":"Red",
               "display_key":"Wine Type",
               "display_value":"Red"
            }
         ],
         "sku":"",
         "price":0,
         "parent_name":null
      }
   ],
   "tax_lines":[
      
   ],
   "shipping_lines":[
      
   ],
   "fee_lines":[
      {
         "id":47,
         "name":"Damage Bond",
         "tax_class":"",
         "tax_status":"taxable",
         "amount":"100",
         "total":"100.00",
         "total_tax":"0.00",
         "taxes":[
            
         ],
         "meta_data":[
            {
               "id":428,
               "key":"damage_bond_paid_to",
               "value":"example@gmail.com",
               "display_key":"damage_bond_paid_to",
               "display_value":"example@gmail.com"
            },
            {
               "id":429,
               "key":"damage_bond_paid_on",
               "value":"today",
               "display_key":"damage_bond_paid_on",
               "display_value":"today"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":48,
         "name":"Booking Fee",
         "tax_class":"",
         "tax_status":"taxable",
         "amount":"",
         "total":"0.00",
         "total_tax":"0.00",
         "taxes":[
            
         ],
         "meta_data":[
            {
               "id":436,
               "key":"dbooing_fee_paid_to",
               "value":"example@gmail.com",
               "display_key":"dbooing_fee_paid_to",
               "display_value":"example@gmail.com"
            },
            {
               "id":437,
               "key":"booking_fee_paid_on",
               "value":"1659890457477",
               "display_key":"booking_fee_paid_on",
               "display_value":"1659890457477"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "coupon_lines":[
      
   ],
   "refunds":[
      
   ],
   "payment_url":"https:\/\/dev1.example.com\/checkout\/order-pay\/87\/?pay_for_order=true&key=wc_order_omQo7nW5yCS9X",
   "date_created_gmt":"2022-08-07T16:40:57",
   "date_modified_gmt":"2022-08-11T10:13:07",
   "date_completed_gmt":null,
   "date_paid_gmt":"2022-08-07T16:40:58",
   "currency_symbol":"$",
   "_links":{
      "self":[
         {
            "href":"https:\/\/dev1.example.com\/wp-json\/wc\/v3\/orders\/87"
         }
      ],
      "collection":[
         {
            "href":"https:\/\/dev1.example.com\/wp-json\/wc\/v3\/orders"
         }
      ],
      "customer":[
         {
            "href":"https:\/\/dev1.example.com\/wp-json\/wc\/v3\/customers\/17"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Please note that the given data is not valid JSON

Comment: @evolutionxbox: edited to add full original json object. I still question its validity to be honest, but that's what I'm being given, and I have a sense that I should be able to get the answer I want from this.

Comment: JSON uses key value pairs separated by colons, for example `"user_id" : 12`. Even if the equal signs could be made valid you have other inconsistencies with their usage, for example `"meta_data="[` where the = is inside the quotes, and `"key=user_created_at"` where it seems you have combined a key and a value into a single string.

Comment: The "actual JSON" is also invalid.

Comment: this might explain why things aren't working. If I'm trying to handle this result as JSON and it's not... I can see that'd cause problems.

hmm. What is it? :-/

Comment: Consider trying to fix the JSON output at the source?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I think that's a great idea. Thanks for the pointers. Appreciated!

Comment: I've fixed the source to actually be JSON, and updated the post - but I'm still struggling to select the metadata.

`  Logger.log(orderDetailsObject) `

returns the entire object (enclosed)


but everytime I try to address the metadata, it seems to return null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `find` method on the array:

```js
const orderDetailsObject = {"id":87,"meta_data":[{"id":1232,"key":"user_created_by","value":"example@gmail.com"},{"id":1233,"key":"user_created_at","value":"1659890457477"},{"id":1234,"key":"good_person_or_silly_sausage","value":"No"}]};

console.log(orderDetailsObject.meta_data.find(
    ({key}) => key == "good_person_or_silly_sausage"
)?.value);
```